# if event is click and drag jquery

Tags: jquery

i have a table
how to change the tr's background color during click and drag?

```
<table id="tables">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>1.</td>
   <td>John Smith</td>
   <td>Male</td>
   <td>Active</td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
   <td>2.</td>
   <td>Pepe Smith</td>
   <td>Female</td>
   <td>Active</td>
  <tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

when i click and drag anywhere in the row.. the background color should change..
is this possible using jquery only?

Comment: How are you dragging it?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said how you're dragging them. **If** you're using [jQuery UI's `Draggable`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) *(can it drag rows?)*, you can either use CSS or events.

**CSS**:

From [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/):

> Draggable elements gets a class of
>   
> `ui-draggable`
>   
> During drag the element also gets a class of
>   
> `ui-draggable-dragging`

And so:

```
#tables tr.ui-draggable-dragging {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

**Events**:

The docs also talk about the `start` and `stop` events, which you could use if you didn't want to use CSS.

Comment: is this possible using only jquery not jquery ui?

Comment: @ricky - it is, if you feel like writing your own draggable plugin.

Comment: @ricky: jQuery itself doesn't have any special drag support (see http://api.jquery.com/ or, of course, the source code). You can, of course, *use* jQuery's features to build dragging (respond to `mousedown` and `mouseup` events, etc.). And if you want to drag rows, you may need to do that as I don't believe jQuery UI's `Draggable` works with rows (at least, it doesn't in this naive test case: http://jsbin.com/amana3 -- in that, I can drag the list items, but not the table rows). Good luck.